# Adding columns with awk. What is wrong with this awk command?

Tags: awk

I want to add two columns to a file with ~10,000 columns. I want to insert as the first column the nr 22 on each row. Then I want the original first column as the second column, then as the third column I want to insert the line nr (NR), and after that I want the rest of the original columns to be printed. I thought I could do that with the following awk line:

```
awk '{print 22, $1, NR; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) print $i}' file
```

It prints the first three columns (22, $1, NR) well, but after that, there is a new line started for each value, so the file is printed like this:

```
22 $1 NR
$2
$3
$4
etc...
```

instead of:

```
22 $1 NR $2 $3 $4 etc...
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `printf` instead since `print` adds a newline.

```
awk '{printf("%d, %d, %d, ", 22, $1, NR); for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) printf("%d, ", i)}' file
```

Or you can play with the `ORS` and `OFS`, the *Output Record Separator* and the *Output Field Separator*. Normally you add those in a `BEGIN` statement like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } {print 22, $1, NR; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) print $i}{print "\n"}' file
```

Note that an extra `printf "\n"` is needed, else everything ends up on one line...

Read more in [gawk manual output separators](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Output-Separators)

Answer (score 1):

For more precise control over the output format than what is provided by [`print`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Print)(which print a newline by default), use [`printf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Printf).