# awk: using escape characters in for statement

Tags: for-loop, escaping, awk

I have the following awk command which works perfectly:

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } {print 22, $1, NR; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) print $i}{print "\n"}' file
```

What it does is insert two columns: the value 22 as the first, and the nr of the row as the third (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821590/adding-columns-with-awk-what-is-wrong-with-this-awk-command)).
I tried running this command in a for loop as follows:

```
for p in 20 21 22
do
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } {print $p, \$1, NR; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) print \$i}{print "\n"}' file > file$p
done
```

So instead of the 22 in the first column, 3 files are made where each file has 20, 21 or 22 as the first column. Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I get the message: *^ backslash not last character on line*.
It probably has something to do with how I escaped the $ characters, but I don't know how else to do it... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a shell-parameter to awk using

```
-v parameter=value
```

i.e. use

```
awk -v p=$p ...
```

Like this:

```
for p in 20 21 22
do
awk -v p=$p 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } [TOO LONG LINE]' file > file$p
done
```

Complete command:

```
for p in 20 21 22; do awk -v p=$p 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } {print p, $1, NR; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) print $i}{print "\n"}' file > file$p; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You are in the right direction. Because your awk script is within ' (single quotes), bash doesn't replace $p with its value in the script (See Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide - Quoting).
You need to do one of the following:
1 (Recommened):

```
for p in 20 21 22
do
awk -v p=$p 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } {print p, \$1, NR; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) print \$i}{print "\n"}' file > file$p
done
```

2: Use " instead of ' and within the awk escape the " by \"

Comment: don't escape the `$` in the awk script.